# How to synchronize result of UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to implement a UINavigationBarDelegate, and I want to show a alert to let user determine whether leave this view.

This is my code:

```
extension CDFFormController: UINavigationBarDelegate {

    public func navigationBar(_ navigationBar: UINavigationBar, shouldPop item: UINavigationItem) -> Bool {
        if let entityViewController = self.topViewController as? MyEntityViewController {
            if entityViewController.isEditing {
                let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
                var result = false
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Leave the view？", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "leave", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                    result = true
                    semaphore.signal()
                }))
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { _ in
                    semaphore.signal()
                }))
                entityViewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                semaphore.wait()
                return result
            } else {
                return true
            }
        } else {
            return true
        }

    }

}
```

I need return the result, so I use DispatchSemaphore to block the method. But the question is: This method is called on main queue, and blocking it means blocking the ui thread and the method never returns.

Or any other solution?

Comment: `UIAlertController`'s .isBeingPresented might turn out to be useful in your case. I used it in my workaround solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43507005/5329717 for another problem, perhaps you will find it helpful in some way.

Comment: Use a completion handler instead.

Comment: This delegate method is called on main thread(ui thread), the alert controller event can't show up until it returns!

Comment: @Sulthan Could you give more explanation?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure it's will be work. I does not tested this.

```
extension CDFFormController: UINavigationBarDelegate {

public func navigationBar(_ navigationBar: UINavigationBar, shouldPop item: UINavigationItem) -> Bool {
    if let entityViewController = self.topViewController as? MyEntityViewController {
        if entityViewController.isEditing {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Leave the view？", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "leave", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                let saveDelegate = navigationBar.delegate;
                navigationBar.delegate = nil;
                navigationBar.popItem(animated:YES);
                navigationBar.delegate = saveDelegate;
            }))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .cancel, handler:nil))
            entityViewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    } else {
        return true
    }

}

}
```

Other way is use RunLoop. But I don't like this.

```
extension CDFFormController: UINavigationBarDelegate {

    public func navigationBar(_ navigationBar: UINavigationBar, shouldPop item: UINavigationItem) -> Bool {
        if let entityViewController = self.topViewController as? MyEntityViewController {
            if entityViewController.isEditing {
                let state = 0
                var result = false
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Leave the view？", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "leave", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                    state = 1

                }))
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { _ in
                    state = 2
                }))
                entityViewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                while (state == 0)
                {
                   RunLoop.current.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.5))
                }
                return state == 1
            } else {
                return true
            }
        } else {
            return true
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: For the first solution, it throws `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cannot manually set the delegate on a UINavigationBar managed by a controller.'`, iOS don't want me to change the delegate, but that is a good point. I think I can use a new flag property to do the same thing like that :)

Comment: I don't like the second one too, nobody like dead-loop :P

Comment: Unfortunately, it throws another `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cannot call popNavigationItemAnimated: directly on a UINavigationBar managed by a controller.'`. But I don't want to manage a UINavigationBar by myself :(

Comment: As I understand you use navigationcontroller. So change pop to the navigation bar on the pop to the navigation controller. Also you can chnage delegate for the navigation controller.