# Customizing UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

Is there a way we can customize the UIAlertController to look like the following:

[image]

Currently, it looks like this:

[image]

I know how to get rid of the cancel action. I just need it to occupy the parent width and change the color scheme and stuff.

If UIAlertController cannot be customized to achieve this, is there any other option that I can use for this? Cannot use 3rd party software, needs to be built in Swift 4.2.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not you are using custom UIView for this?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. Is there an example I can look at for this? Pretty new to iOS.

Comment: Do you know how to make design on Storyboard? If know then design the save view on the storyboard same as your desired UI that you want instead of using UIAlertController.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom View in UIAlertController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43505737/custom-view-in-uialertcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

This really seems like a UIView with a TableView inside it... if you can't use any third party software you might struggle to make it... but you can check this question to see if it helps [How to embed a UITableView in a custom view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688938/how-to-embed-a-uitableview-in-a-custom-view)

Answer (score 0):

Your custom design can't be obtained by configuring an instance of UIAlertController.

You have to create your own custom UIView or UIViewController.